# Why don't python strings have an __iter__ method?

Tags: python, string, iteration

How is it that we can iterate over python strings when strings don't provide an `__iter__` method?

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "asdf".__iter__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__'
>>> it = iter("asdf")      
>>> it
<iterator object at 0xb736f5ac>
>>>
```

My understanding [from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) is that an `__iter__` method is required for iteration. Why don't Python strings follow the same convention, and how do they provide iteration without doing so?

Comment: Its worth pointing out that in Python 3, strings do have __iter__.

Comment: It is all a matter of history, no?  The idea of iterators originated to generalize generator functions, but the for loop had been there all along, depending upon a different signature.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From your link:

> or it must support the sequence
>   protocol (the `__getitem__()` method
>   with integer arguments starting at 0).

```
In [1]: 'foo'.__getitem__(0)
Out[1]: 'f'
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably because Python isn't a langage that has a "char" type. The natural thing to return, if string did have `__iter__` would be chars, but there are no chars. I can see a case for hooking `__iter__` up to string and doing whatever list(someString) does, not really sure why it's not that way.

Comment: `>>> list(iter('abcd'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`
Python uses one-character strings instead.

Comment: Right but if string (in Python 2) _did_ have an `__iter__`, should it iterate over single character strings or over integers (0 - 255)? It's not obvious which is better so they probably skipped it. If there were a unicode `__iter__` though it should definitely iterate over single character strings, so not sure why that's not in Python.

Comment: In Python2 iterating over string or unicode yields single character strings or unicode respectively.  `list(iter(u'abcd')) == [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']`  This leads to the strange situation that each of the elements in `'a'` is the same as the whole sequence making it effectively an infinitely nested sequence.

Comment: @Singletoned What's wrong with that? Look at all the elements in a (mathematical) empty set.

Comment: @Griffin What's wrong with that is that it works a bit like a list, but not entirely like one.  It's a leaky abstraction that means that about half the type checking I do is testing whether an iterable is a basestring or not.  EG when recursively descending through deeply nested data structures, you have to be careful not to iterate over strings.