# str object in Python 2.7 doesn't have __iter__, yet it act like iterable. Why?

Tags: string, iterator, python-2.7

I was checking out str objects in Python, and I realized that str object in Python 2.7 doesn't have either `__iter__()` method nor `next()` method, while in Python 3.0 str objects have `__iter__()` method, and thus they are iterable. However, I can still use str objects as if they are iterable's in Python 2.7. For example, I can use them in for loops. How does this work?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113133/why-do-python-strings-not-have-iter-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: because `iter(s)` returns an iterable object.

Longer answer: `iter()` looks for an `__iter__()` method, but if it doesn't find one it tries to construct and iterator itself. Any object that supports `__getitem__()` with integer indices starting at 0 can be used to create a simple iterator. `__getitem__()` is the function behind list/string indexing operations, eg `s[0]`.

```
>>> "abc".__iter__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__'
>>> iter("abc")
<iterator object at 0x1004ad790>
>>> iter("abc").next()
'a'
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) for details.