# Flattened out a mixed type of list

Tags: python, list

I have a mixed list that looked like this:

```
[('1CFV',), 'NONRBP', [0.00325071141379, 0.278046326931, 0.291350892759]]
```

It was created with this command:

```
In [12]: l1 =  [0.00325071141379, 0.278046326931, 0.291350892759]

In [13]: t1 = ('1CFV',)                                                          

In [14]: s1 = "NONRBP"

In [15]: mixl = [t1,s1,l1]

In [16]: mixl
```

Is there a way to convert it into:

```
   ['1CFV', 'NONRBP', 0.00325071141379, 0.278046326931, 0.291350892759]
```

I tried this, but it flattened out even the string 'NONRBP' which is not what I want:

```
 [item for sublist in mixl for item in sublist]
```

Comment: There are solutions to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176742/python-3-replacement-for-deprecated-compiler-ast-flatten-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> final = []
>>> a = [('1CFV',), 'NONRBP', [0.00325071141379, 0.278046326931, 0.291350892759]]
>>> for i in a:
...   if hasattr(i, '__iter__'):
...     for j in i:
...       final.append(j)
...   else:
...     final.append(i)
... 
>>> print final
['1CFV', 'NONRBP', 0.00325071141379, 0.27804632693100001, 0.291350892759]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for python3. `str` does have a member function `__iter__`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113133) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
[item for item in list if type(item) is not list] + 
[item for sublist in mixl if type(item) is list for item in sublist]
```

Solves the specific case where a list contains lists and other iterables (strings)